# Need help with the following lemma about transpositions

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

If $1 \leq k <l \leq n$ and $\sigma=(k,l)$ then the number of inversions of $\sigma$ is $2(l-k)-1$. Thus every transposition is an odd transposition.

I don't understand why the number of inversions would be such expression. The transposition $\sigma$ is just a 2 cycle, so I don't see how it can have more than 1 inversion.

Comment: I believe they are taking an inversion to be 'swapping' two adjacent values. So take (2,7) for example, this would be achieved by swapping 2 and 3, then 2 and 4... until 2 with 7, and then swapping the 7 all the way back to the 2 slot.

Comment: can you elaborate on that write it as product of cycles?

Comment: I'll write a series of strings of 5 numbers to illustrate my point with (2,4); start= 1234 \\ 1324 \\ 1342 \\ 1432 = end. Notice that only adjacent positions are being swapped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to define the number of inversions is, the total number of pairs $i<j$ with $\sigma(i)>\sigma(j)$. So when you switch $k$ and $l$, $k$ gets moved past every number between $k$ and $l$ and so does $l$. Thus the inversions are: the pair $k,l$; and the pairs $k,i$ and $i,l$ for *every* $i$ strictly between $k$ and $l$. There are $l-k-1$ numbers $i$ between $k$ and $l$, and each contributes $2$ inversions ($k,i$ and $i,l$); and $k,l$ is also an inversion. So the total is $2\times (k-l-1) + 1$, which is equivalent to the formula in the OP.

Comment: why?, I just see $(k,l)$ as a 2 cycle. k goes to l and l goes to k. That's it right?. Maybe I am misunderstanding $(k,l)$ .

Comment: You're correct about what $(k,l)$ means but you're misunderstanding the definition of inversions. An inversion is *every* pair of inputs for which the output switches the order. For example: Consider the permutation $\sigma = (2,4)$. This switches 2 and 4 as you say. It doesn't move 3. But this means that if you input 2 and 3, well, 2 outputs to 4 and 3 outputs to 3. So while $2<3$, $\sigma(2)=4>\sigma(3)=3$. So $2,3$ is an inversion.

Comment: An inversion is an order pair $(i,j)$ in $\sigma$ such that $\sigma(i)>\sigma(j)$

Comment: To make it fully explicit, $(2,4)$ has three inversions: $\{2,4\}$, $\{2,3\}$, and $\{3,4\}$. The point is that in each of these cases, the outputs have the reverse order of the inputs. You can check the condition $\sigma(i)>\sigma(j)$ in each case.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhh right , right, so we also have to consider all the elements that are mapped to itself which can also create inversions with the elements in the given cycle.

Comment: Yep, you've got it now.

Comment: I have another question. What does $N(\sigma(k,k+1))$ stand for?. N counts the number of inversions , but I am confused about the $(k,k+1)$

Comment: Maybe $\sigma (k,k+1)$ is the composition of $\sigma$ with $(k,k+1)$, i.e. the permutation obtained by applying one of these and then the other? What is meant would then depend on whether your text uses the left-to-right or right-to-left convention in composing permutations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43786/discussion-between-themathnoob-and-ben-blum-smith).

Answer (score 6):

the identity permutation looks like this:

$1,2,3\dots n-1,n$

After transposing $k$ and $l$ it looks like this:

$1,2,3\dots\color{red}{l,k+1,\dots,l-1,k},l+1\dots n$, notice that every pair containing $l$ and a red integer, or $k$ and a red integer, is an inversion.